# Is there a way in Java to execute consecutive lines of code asynchronously?

Tags: java

I have Java code in which there are two lines, say:

```
//Line 1 - This line makes a db call and fetches some result
//Line 2 - This line make a REST call and fetches another result of data.
```

Now as the above two lines are completely independent what i am looking for is that whether i can execute the above two line in a parallel manner. Like the control should go to the line Line 2 immediately without waiting for the line 1 to finish execution. The whole idea to is improve the performance of the application.Please let me know if someone has any solution.

Note: It's a Spring-based application.

Comment: Spring WebFlux is designed for that kind of thing. But it's quite complex. And if you're JDBC or JPA, it's not adapted. Of course, you could also submit the two jobs to an executor and use Futures. If you have no idea where to start, I'd say that you probably don't want to significantly increase the complexity of your app for a gain that will probably be marginal.

Comment: @JBNizet JDBC is not adapted if multiple threads use DB connection. But if the second uses a REST call, is it really not adapted?

Comment: JDBC is a blocking, synchronous API. WebFlux consists in using very few threads and doing all the IO asynchronously, using non-blocking calls.

Comment: You're talking about making your app multithreaded and/or executing operations asynchronously.  The Java language and Standard Library have built-in features to do both of these things.  Third party libraries in some cases are written to support parallel execution as well.  So to some degree, it depends on just what you're using to perform your two operations, as @JBNizet points out.  And, as JB points out as well, adding multithreading and asynchronous behavior both add complexity to your app.  I would suggest that you worry about this later, when you notice an actual performance problem.